# TypeError list object is not callable when trying to convert an object to a string

Tags: python, string, csv

Using python, I imported a csv file with a list of names. I wanted to clean up the data by removing any trailing `;,?` characters. I found out about the strip function in python and decided to use it. What I noticed was that it did not do anything to the text. I noticed that python does not see it as a string. When I ran `item is str`, it would return false. When I try to use `str(item)`, it would say 'list' object is not callable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have rebound `str` to a list object. Don't do that, you are masking the built-in type:

```
>>> str(42)
'42'
>>> str = ['foo', 'bar']
>>> str(42)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Note that the *correct* way to test for the type of an object is to use [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
isinstance(item, str)
```

although in a debugging session, you can also use `type()` to introspect the object, or use `repr()` to get a helpful Python literal represention (if available, otherwise a representation suitable for debugging is given):

```
>>> str = ['foo', 'bar']
>>> type(str)
<type 'list'>
>>> print repr(str)
['foo', 'bar']
>>> del str
>>> type(str)
<type 'type'>
>>> print repr(str)
<type 'str'>
```